# Express- MVC - separate model file to create new user

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Small app to create users, app have 2 files  (app.js) and  business logic file (models/users.js) , the erro msg happens when you wan to create new user as following :

**Error Msg**

```
var newuser = new userAA({
              ^

TypeError: userAA is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (e:\2016\db-mongoose-seperat-file\db-MONGOOSE-seperate.js:25:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
```

**my user.model.js**

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');

//schema
var userSchema =mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        index:true
            },
    password:{type:String},
    email:{type:String},
    name:{type:String}
});

// export model
module.exports=mongoose.model('usermodel',userSchema);

// export model methods
module.exports={
    dummyfunc:function (){ console.log("Dummy func111111111"); },
    dummyfunc2:function (){ console.log("Dummy func2222222"); },
};
```

**my app.js**

```
var express=require('express');
var http= require('http');
var app=express();
var mongoose=require('mongoose');

// connect to db
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/logindb2');

// include  mongoose schema-model  to app.js
var userAA=require('./models/users.models');

userAA.dummyfunc();
userAA.dummyfunc2();


// ERROR in the following line 'userAA' is not a function

var newuser = new userAA({

    username:"Mr.Zombi",
    password:"mJdmOdmn3k=34",
    email:"eee@eskander.com",
    name:"f.name"
});

app.get("/",function(req,res){
     userAA.dummyfunc();
     userAA.find({},function(err,docs){
     console.log(docs);
     res.send(docs);
    });   
});

http.createServer(app).listen(5000,function(){
    console.log('Run db-MONGOOSE Server app');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using module.exports twice. Removing

```
module.exports={
dummyfunc:function (){ console.log("Dummy func111111111"); },
dummyfunc2:function (){ console.log("Dummy func2222222"); },
};
```

and

```
userAA.dummyfunc();
userAA.dummyfunc2();
```

will make it work.